# OpenCV svm in the primal form(absolute of alpha )

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

In the primal form. few values of alpha in svm are positive and the corresponding x will be the support vectors as shown http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine.

Correct if i am wrong, SVM in OpenCV is in Primal form? Then the question is why opencv takes the **absolute** value of alpha and also it is multiplied by y?and the checks if greater than 0?

This can be seen:

```
for( i = 0; i < sample_count; i++ )
    alpha[i] *= y[i];
```

What i meant can be seen as it counts the support vectors if the absolute is larger than 0

```
 for( i = 0; i < sample_count; i++ )
        sv_count += fabs(alpha[i]) > 0;
```

Comment: Actually, you can get both the forms from the OpenCV implementation since it uses [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf).. Read the paper I linked for more information.

Comment: I know, but in the case of OpenCV, it is primal?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV form is in the dual. The primal does not have the alphas. They simply rolled the sign of the label into the sign of the alphas since the alphas must be positive - saves on space and ups.